# how to return comma seperated values in oracle SP

Tags: oracle, plsql

If I have a simple query like:

```
OPEN cursor FOR 
SELECT USER_ID FROM USER_TABLE WHERE USER_ID = V_SOME_USER;
```

this will return records in different rows but how can I return the rows in the following format:

```
'userid1', 'userid2', 'userid3'.....'useridN'
```

I want to do this because I want to send this off as a `parameter` to another stored procedure...Also, what is the limit on how big the `string` can be when passed to the SP as parameter

What I have so far:

```
    l_str  varchar2(32767) default null;
    l_sep  varchar2(10) default null;
    l_sep1  varchar2(10) default null;
begin
    for x in ( SELECT USER_ID FROM USER_TABLE WHERE USER_ID = V_SOME_USER ) loop
        l_str := l_str || l_sep || x.b || l_sep;
       l_sep := '''';
       l_sep1 := ''',';
   end loop;
```

Though this doesnt give expected results

Comment: We can pass a REF CURSOR as a parameter.  So why not do that instead?

Comment: that would be better...since i was thinking in strings it would have character limit.  Still how do i put `'userid1', 'userid2'...` format results in ref cursor?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Though you should explore the other ways of doing this. In case you need so, there is a easy way, albeit there is a catch.

Which version of Oracle you are using? Oracle 11gR2 have a nice implementation, [`LISTAGG`](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e10592/functions087.htm).

Like -

```
SELECT LISTAGG(last_name, ', ') 
    WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY hire_date, last_name) "Emp_list",
    MIN(hire_date) "Earliest"
    FROM employees
    WHERE department_id = 30;

Emp_list                                                     Earliest
------------------------------------------------------------ ---------
Raphaely, Khoo, Tobias, Baida, Himuro, Colmenares            07-DEC-02
```

Check out.